Mass moment of inertia flipping in different mediums
Consider someone performing a front flip in the water versus in the air. Assume the body position in both cases to be identical. In which case would the mass moment of inertia be greater and why?
Prof hinted towards the medium not being affected. I believe because the persons mass doesn’t change in the different mediums. Buoyancy was not covered.

More than the body has to move...
